# Wrapping data in a Pdf cell using fpdf for PHP in my project for print invoice

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

[image: when i enter more data its overflow from the cell]

i want to wrap data in one cell when i use fpdf function to add more data 
using php

```
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,"".$row['asdsa'],1,1,"l");
$pdf->SetXY(111,50);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,"invoice no :",1,0,"l");
$pdf->Cell(40, 20, 'asdasdasdas dsadsad', 1, 1, 'L');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function MultiCell, which allows for printing of multiple lines.

```
$pdf->MultiCell( 40, 20, $text, 1);
```

The documentation is here:
http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm

Otherwise, if you want to use Cell. I would suggest wrapping the text yourself.

Example code of this can be found here:
[column text wrap using fpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731744/column-text-wrap-using-fpdf)